# How to keep the background color/opacity of hovered area while darkening the rest of the html page?

Tags: javascript, background, hover, mousemove

I am trying to write a code that enables the user to hover with the mouse cursor on a given html page (i am using Lorem Ipsum text in my question). While hovering a page wide div of a certain height stays with the original background color/opacity, while the rest of the html gets darken.
I only succeeded doing the opposite, darkening the hovered area while leaving the rest of the html with its original background color/opacity.

Appreciate the help.

```js
$("html").bind("mousemove", function (e) {
  $("#follower").css({
    left: 0,
    top: e.pageY - 100,
  });
  $("#follower").css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
    
#follower {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  /* z-index: 999; */
}
    
.lorem {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="follower"></div>
    <div class="lorem">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin elementum
      enim id erat dapibus molestie. Ut enim urna, dictum nec erat sed,
      tincidunt lacinia enim. Suspendisse felis tellus, tincidunt id fringilla
      non, hendrerit sit amet velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
      primis in faucibus. Morbi ante ante, vehicula in nisl eget, pretium varius
      ligula. Curabitur et nulla malesuada, convallis nibh vel, viverra dolor.
      Curabitur quis libero posuere, ultrices nisl id, finibus massa. Sed
      fermentum sapien et dui eleifend interdum. Maecenas vehicula nunc sed diam
      vulputate ornare. Praesent urna eros, congue vitae porttitor nec, tempor
      et eros. Quisque eget condimentum justo. Sed maximus sem sapien, ac
      aliquet tortor semper non. Nulla in velit facilisis, sollicitudin mauris
      vitae, ultricies diam. Phasellus varius viverra pellentesque. Suspendisse
      volutpat mollis nisi, et dapibus dui tristique ac. In vitae blandit est,
      eget pretium lorem. Suspendisse est augue, porta vel scelerisque in,
      sollicitudin fermentum lorem. Quisque vestibulum eros eu arcu finibus, ut
      congue metus cursus. Morbi lacinia et ligula non eleifend. Vivamus sed
      sagittis lectus. Duis id pellentesque tellus, in malesuada tellus. Duis
      vulputate justo ac auctor eleifend. Ut egestas urna id felis suscipit
      consequat. Vivamus iaculis vel justo ac finibus. Sed rhoncus nec magna
      eget aliquam. Donec quam lorem, eleifend ac dui non, volutpat pretium
      quam. Curabitur venenatis vel nulla ac molestie. In sed ultrices nibh, a
      pretium leo. Proin hendrerit ultrices ullamcorper. Quisque iaculis felis
      ac dolor mollis, non auctor justo pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant
      morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      Cras vel arcu bibendum, mattis massa ac, viverra lorem. Duis malesuada
      nisl ligula, ac rhoncus justo vehicula et. Proin suscipit lacus ac risus
      dignissim porta. Maecenas luctus, lacus non dignissim aliquam, odio augue
      euismod enim, et tristique lectus ante et eros. Fusce eleifend tortor
      nisl, ac lobortis mauris dapibus et. Vivamus elementum pulvinar turpis,
      vel auctor enim commodo nec. Donec suscipit efficitur sapien at gravida.
      Fusce pulvinar venenatis metus at aliquet. Mauris blandit rutrum erat ut
      rutrum. Proin rutrum suscipit dui, vitae ornare diam ultrices non. Vivamus
      feugiat ut dui sollicitudin iaculis. Nunc nec viverra mauris. Ut in mauris
      sem. Pellentesque eu hendrerit lorem. Sed nec ex ac sapien pellentesque
      iaculis ut eget sem. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque aliquet aliquam dui
      vitae dapibus. Donec vel consectetur nibh. Mauris vel semper nunc, ac
      sodales ligula. Curabitur iaculis felis a lorem pharetra, sed accumsan
      neque tempus. Vivamus a purus nunc. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
      magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend
      lorem, nec efficitur metus. Morbi gravida ante vel turpis aliquam
      pellentesque. Duis dignissim rhoncus nisi. Aliquam finibus iaculis tortor,
      nec ullamcorper nulla rhoncus varius. Etiam lobortis felis in arcu sodales
      iaculis. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean feugiat ipsum ut egestas pulvinar.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin elementum
      enim id erat dapibus molestie. Ut enim urna, dictum nec erat sed,
      tincidunt lacinia enim. Suspendisse felis tellus, tincidunt id fringilla
      non, hendrerit sit amet velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
      primis in faucibus. Morbi ante ante, vehicula in nisl eget, pretium varius
      ligula. Curabitur et nulla malesuada, convallis nibh vel, viverra dolor.
      Curabitur quis libero posuere, ultrices nisl id, finibus massa.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating one overlapping div, create two divs that make the background opaque where the user is not hovering.

```js
$("html").bind("mousemove", function (e) {
  $("#upper").css({
    left: 0,
    height: e.pageY - 100,
  });
  $("#lower").css({
    left: 0,
    height: "unset",
    top: e.pageY,
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#upper {
  top: 0px;
}

#lower {
  height: 0vh;
}
    
.lorem {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="upper" class="overlay"></div>
<div id="lower" class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="lorem">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin elementum
      enim id erat dapibus molestie. Ut enim urna, dictum nec erat sed,
      tincidunt lacinia enim. Suspendisse felis tellus, tincidunt id fringilla
      non, hendrerit sit amet velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
      primis in faucibus. Morbi ante ante, vehicula in nisl eget, pretium varius
      ligula. Curabitur et nulla malesuada, convallis nibh vel, viverra dolor.
      Curabitur quis libero posuere, ultrices nisl id, finibus massa. Sed
      fermentum sapien et dui eleifend interdum. Maecenas vehicula nunc sed diam
      vulputate ornare. Praesent urna eros, congue vitae porttitor nec, tempor
      et eros. Quisque eget condimentum justo. Sed maximus sem sapien, ac
      aliquet tortor semper non. Nulla in velit facilisis, sollicitudin mauris
      vitae, ultricies diam. Phasellus varius viverra pellentesque. Suspendisse
      volutpat mollis nisi, et dapibus dui tristique ac. In vitae blandit est,
      eget pretium lorem. Suspendisse est augue, porta vel scelerisque in,
      sollicitudin fermentum lorem. Quisque vestibulum eros eu arcu finibus, ut
      congue metus cursus. Morbi lacinia et ligula non eleifend. Vivamus sed
      sagittis lectus. Duis id pellentesque tellus, in malesuada tellus. Duis
      vulputate justo ac auctor eleifend. Ut egestas urna id felis suscipit
      consequat. Vivamus iaculis vel justo ac finibus. Sed rhoncus nec magna
      eget aliquam. Donec quam lorem, eleifend ac dui non, volutpat pretium
      quam. Curabitur venenatis vel nulla ac molestie. In sed ultrices nibh, a
      pretium leo. Proin hendrerit ultrices ullamcorper. Quisque iaculis felis
      ac dolor mollis, non auctor justo pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant
      morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      Cras vel arcu bibendum, mattis massa ac, viverra lorem. Duis malesuada
      nisl ligula, ac rhoncus justo vehicula et. Proin suscipit lacus ac risus
      dignissim porta. Maecenas luctus, lacus non dignissim aliquam, odio augue
      euismod enim, et tristique lectus ante et eros. Fusce eleifend tortor
      nisl, ac lobortis mauris dapibus et. Vivamus elementum pulvinar turpis,
      vel auctor enim commodo nec. Donec suscipit efficitur sapien at gravida.
      Fusce pulvinar venenatis metus at aliquet. Mauris blandit rutrum erat ut
      rutrum. Proin rutrum suscipit dui, vitae ornare diam ultrices non. Vivamus
      feugiat ut dui sollicitudin iaculis. Nunc nec viverra mauris. Ut in mauris
      sem. Pellentesque eu hendrerit lorem. Sed nec ex ac sapien pellentesque
      iaculis ut eget sem. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque aliquet aliquam dui
      vitae dapibus. Donec vel consectetur nibh. Mauris vel semper nunc, ac
      sodales ligula. Curabitur iaculis felis a lorem pharetra, sed accumsan
      neque tempus. Vivamus a purus nunc. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
      magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc eget eleifend
      lorem, nec efficitur metus. Morbi gravida ante vel turpis aliquam
      pellentesque. Duis dignissim rhoncus nisi. Aliquam finibus iaculis tortor,
      nec ullamcorper nulla rhoncus varius. Etiam lobortis felis in arcu sodales
      iaculis. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean feugiat ipsum ut egestas pulvinar.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin elementum
      enim id erat dapibus molestie. Ut enim urna, dictum nec erat sed,
      tincidunt lacinia enim. Suspendisse felis tellus, tincidunt id fringilla
      non, hendrerit sit amet velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
      primis in faucibus. Morbi ante ante, vehicula in nisl eget, pretium varius
      ligula. Curabitur et nulla malesuada, convallis nibh vel, viverra dolor.
      Curabitur quis libero posuere, ultrices nisl id, finibus massa.
    </div>
```